# I can't building google cloud endpoints sample project

Tags: java, maven, log4j, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I want to running "Getting Started with Endpoints Frameworks on App Engine".
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/get-started-frameworks-java?hl=ja

but, I can't building sample project.
"java-docs-samples/appengine-java8/endpoints-frameworks-v2/backend."

error is
"Class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger does not implement Log"

anyone help me..

Comment: ----
Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T16:58:13+09:00)
Java version: 1.8.0_60, vendor: Oracle Corporation
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.13.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
----

Comment: Please post full logs, rather than just one line.

Comment: I fixed! I must write "org.apache.maven.wagon" and "log4j" dependency in pom.xml.
It is not write in sample project. google mistake it.
thank you saiyr.